# Flexlayout make material button bigger in height

Tags: angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I have the following html but this is making the button grow bigger in size. How to make the button not grow in height ?

```
  <div fxLayout="row">
    <h5>User Management</h5>
    <span fxFlex></span>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Create</button>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution with `fxLayoutAlign` directive**

The simplest way is to use the [`fxLayoutAlign`](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutAlign-API) directive on your `div` element as shown below.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
  ... 
</div>
```

**Solution with CSS**

The problem in your HTML template is that the `h5` element is the tallest element and that all other elements in the row are laid out with same height. One possible solution is to remove the top and bottom margins from the `h5` element using CSS.

```
h5 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

In case you have other `h5` elements on the same page that must not be altered, you need to define a specific CSS class for the `h5` element that appears in the flex row (it could be named "h5-inline").

```
.h5-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The HTML template would then look like this.

```
<div fxLayout="row">
  <h5 class="h5-inline">User Management</h5>
  <span fxFlex></span>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Create</button>
</div>
```